# How to set URL query params in Vue with Vue-Router

Tags: javascript, vue-router, vue.js

I am trying to set query params with [Vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router) when changing input fields, I don't want to navigate to some other page but just want to modify URL query params on the same page, I am doing this:

```js
    this.$router.replace({ query: { q1: "q1" } })
```

But this also refreshes the page and sets the y position to 0, ie scrolls to the top of the page. Is this the correct way to set the URL query params or is there a better way to do it?

---

Edited:

Here is my router code:

```js
    export default new Router({
      mode: 'history',
      scrollBehavior: (to, from, savedPosition)  => {
        if (to.hash) {
          return {selector: to.hash}
        } else {
          return {x: 0, y: 0}
        }
      },
      routes: [
        ....... 
        { path: '/user/:id', component: UserView },
      ]
    })
```

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Here is the example in docs:

```
// with query, resulting in /register?plan=private
router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' }})
```

Ref: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

As mentioned in those docs, `router.replace` works like `router.push`

So, you seem to have it right in your sample code in question. But I think you may need to include either `name` or `path` parameter also, so that the router has some route to navigate to. Without a `name` or `path`, it does not look very meaningful.

This is my current understanding now:

- `query` is optional for router - some additional info for the component to construct the view
- `name` or `path` is mandatory - it decides what component to show in your `<router-view>`.

That might be the missing thing in your sample code.

**EDIT: Additional details after comments**

Have you tried using **named routes** in this case? You have dynamic routes, and it is easier to provide params and query separately:

```
routes: [
    { name: 'user-view', path: '/user/:id', component: UserView },
    // other routes
]
```

and then in your methods:

```
this.$router.replace({ name: "user-view", params: {id:"123"}, query: {q1: "q1"} })
```

Technically there is no difference between the above and `this.$router.replace({path: "/user/123", query:{q1: "q1"}})`, but it is easier to supply dynamic params on named routes than composing the route string. In either cases, query params should be taken into account. In either case, I couldn't find anything wrong with the way query params are handled.

After you are inside the route, you can fetch your dynamic params as `this.$route.params.id` and your query params as `this.$route.query.q1`.

Comment: I tried giving the path also, but this did not stop scrolling to the top of the page, I have edited the question with router options also, may be there is some change needed there.

Comment: Is your query param intended to scroll to the right place in the document? Like your other question on [anchor tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341939/how-to-create-anchor-tags-with-vue-router)?

Comment: No, I just want to add the query param in URL, I don't want any scroll here.

Comment: I just tested the options in my local setup, the query params work normally. I am able to navigate to new route and access query params as shown in my updated answer. So, the problem is - you do not want it to scroll? Or the problem is the entire app refreshing again?

Comment: so I am on the same page, when I select some input, I want to add them in the URL, but when I do it, scroll happens. Scroll is the issue for me. I am not trying to navigate to other page, I just want to be on same page and add/modify url query params seemlessly.

Comment: Here is an [old discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/463) on this topic. The only way to change query params is to use `$router.push` or `$router.replace`, which navigates to the same route again. Now the component is refreshed and it scrolls back to top. If you are trying to do infinite-scroll or equivalent, your only option is to identify the query params, process it and scroll to the relevant section in the bottom somehow. Based on my current knowledge, I don't think you can change query params while remaining in the same route. Maybe we can wait for a different answer.

Comment: it does not work for me.       goToConnect() {
        this.$router.push({name: 'Dash.Client.Connect', query:{q1: 'q1'}, params: {email: 'abc'} })
      }

Comment: how can I set the query params in `hash` mode

Comment: @masongzhi If you do not set `history` mode, vue router will automatically stay in its `hash` mode default. You can view the [config reference here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html). To get `hash` mode, skip any reference to `mode` in vue-router config.

Comment: is it possible to do this in the template with a <router-link> tag? adding a query param, i know i can set the "to" attribute to the route name but not sure about "query" param. may be a separate question i didn't see an SO question about this

Comment: this doesn't work with nuxt. when you provide name param, and your route is for example categories/:id, then it will replace route with /categories, ignoring the :id, even if you provide proper path and query. And without name param, it will simply fail to do anything at all (

Answer (score 39):

**Without reloading** the page or refreshing the dom, `history.pushState` can do the job.
Add this method in your component or elsewhere to do that:

```js
addParamsToLocation(params) {
  history.pushState(
    {},
    null,
    this.$route.path +
      '?' +
      Object.keys(params)
        .map(key => {
          return (
            encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key])
          )
        })
        .join('&')
  )
}
```

So anywhere in your component, call `addParamsToLocation({foo: 'bar'})` to push the current location with query params in the window.history stack.

To add query params to current location **without pushing a new history** entry, use `history.replaceState` instead.

Tested with Vue 2.6.10 and Nuxt 2.8.1.

**Be careful with this method!**
Vue Router don't know that url has changed, so it doesn't reflect url after pushState.

Comment: In Vue3 setup api you need to use window.history.pushState

Answer (score 30):

Actually you can push query like this: `this.$router.push({query: {plan: 'private'}})`

Based on: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1631

Comment: "But this also refreshes the page"

Comment: Not sure about Vue2 but works like a charm in Vue3 (without page-refresh)

Comment: @ArnovanOordt It also reloads the page in Vue 3.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here about what "refreshes the page" means here. A hard refresh (like F5) and an actual vue-router client-side navigation are 2 different things. Here, jean's solution does not trigger a "page hard refresh", meanwhile it will trigger a vue-router navigation and possible mount/unmount specific components. Things that OP do not want indeed.

Answer (score 29):

Okay so i've been trying to add a param to my existing url wich already have params for a week now lol,
original url: `http://localhost:3000/somelink?param1=test1`
i've been trying with:

```
this.$router.push({path: this.$route.path, query: {param2: test2} });
```

this code would juste remove param1 and becomes
`http://localhost:3000/somelink?param2=test2`

to solve this issue i used `fullPath`

```
this.$router.push({path: this.$route.fullPath, query: {param2: test2} });
```

now i successfully added params over old params nd the result is

`http://localhost:3000/somelink?param1=test1&param2=test2`

Answer (score 19):

If you are trying to keep some parameters, while changing others, be sure to copy the state of the vue router query and not reuse it.

This works, since you are making an unreferenced copy:

```
  const query = Object.assign({}, this.$route.query);
  query.page = page;
  query.limit = rowsPerPage;
  await this.$router.push({ query });
```

while below will lead to Vue Router thinking you are reusing the same query and lead to the `NavigationDuplicated` error:

```
  const query = this.$route.query;
  query.page = page;
  query.limit = rowsPerPage;
  await this.$router.push({ query });
```

Of course, you could decompose the query object, such as follows, but you'll need to be aware of all the query parameters to your page, otherwise you risk losing them in the resultant navigation.

```
  const { page, limit, ...otherParams } = this.$route.query;
  await this.$router.push(Object.assign({
    page: page,
    limit: rowsPerPage
  }, otherParams));
);
```

Note, while the above example is for `push()`, this works with `replace()` too.

Tested with vue-router 3.1.6.

Answer (score 14):

Here's my simple solution to update the query params in the URL without refreshing the page. Make sure it works for your use case.

```js
const query = { ...this.$route.query, someParam: 'some-value' };
this.$router.replace({ query });
```

Comment: How do you access this.$route.query in vue3 composition API ?

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 for accessing the root element in Composition API i use `import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'` on top and in the code `const root = getCurrentInstance();` and `var query = root.proxy.$route.query`

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 check that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67357142/8816585

Comment: I would recomend `import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';` and then `const route = useRoute();` and `console.log('query', route.query);`

Answer (score 9):

My solution, no refreshing the page and no error `Avoided redundant navigation to current location`

```
    this.$router.replace(
      {
        query: Object.assign({ ...this.$route.query }, { newParam: 'value' }),
      },
      () => {}
    )
```

Comment: This causes page to scroll to top.

Answer (score 7):

You could also just use the browser `window.history.replaceState` API. It doesn't remount any components and doesn't cause redundant navigation.

```
window.history.replaceState(null, '', '?query=myquery');
```

[More info here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState)

Comment: second argument should be a string, so `window.history.replaceState(null, '', '?query=myquery');`

Comment: The `Vue-router` will throw a history state missing warning. So instead of null, pass the `history.state`  like:
`window.history.replaceState(history.state, '', '?query=myquery');`

Answer (score 6):

```
this.$router.push({ query: Object.assign(this.$route.query, { new: 'param' }) })
```

Comment: I liked this answer the best.  Unfortunately this causes `Error: Avoided redundant navigation to current location`

Comment: Fix: `this.$router.push({ query: Object.assign({...this.$route.query}, { new: 'param' }) })`

Comment: But now that I think about it you can just do `this.$router.push({ query: {...this.$route.query,new: 'param'},) })`

Comment: How do you access this.$route.query in vue3 composition API ?

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 Something like:
```js
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const router = useRouter();
const route = useRoute();

// then in your logic
const query = Object.assign(route.value.query, { new: 'param' });
router.value.push({ query });
```

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 check that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67357142/8816585

Answer (score 5):

For adding multiple query params, this is what worked for me (from here https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-programmatically-append-to-querystring/3655/5).

> an answer above was close … though with Object.assign it will mutate this.$route.query which is not what you want to do … make sure the first argument is {} when doing Object.assign

```
this.$router.push({ query: Object.assign({}, this.$route.query, { newKey: 'newValue' }) });
```

Answer (score 3):

To set/remove multiple query params at once I've ended up with the methods below as part of my global mixins (`this` points to vue component):

```
    setQuery(query){
        let obj = Object.assign({}, this.$route.query);

        Object.keys(query).forEach(key => {
            let value = query[key];
            if(value){
                obj[key] = value
            } else {
                delete obj[key]
            }
        })
        this.$router.replace({
            ...this.$router.currentRoute,
            query: obj
        })
    },

    removeQuery(queryNameArray){
        let obj = {}
        queryNameArray.forEach(key => {
            obj[key] = null
        })
        this.setQuery(obj)
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

I normally use the history object for this. It also does not reload the page.

Example:

```
history.pushState({}, '', 
                `/pagepath/path?query=${this.myQueryParam}`);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the equivalent using the Composition API

```html
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
const router = useRouter()

router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' }})
</script>
```

You can also use the Vue devtools just to be sure that it's working as expected (by inspecting the given route you're on) as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74136917/8816585

---

#### Update

That will meanwhile mount/unmount components. Some [vanilla JS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68002518/8816585) is still the best way to go for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The vue router keeps reloading the page on update, the best solution is

```
  const url = new URL(window.location);
  url.searchParams.set('q', 'q');
  window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question has been answered a bunch of times in the last 7 years, but here is the late **2023 solution** that I am using and that works for me.

First you have to make sure that router view has a `:key`: `<RouterView :key="$route.fullPath" />`

this will make sure that the current route will reload if there is ANY change in the current browser URL.

Next, when something happens within the page - you just have to append any non-breaking value to a current URL. I simply append current unix timestamp as a query parameter value, i.e.:

```js
import { useRouter} from 'vue-router'

const onClick = async () => {
  router.replace({
        name: 'order',
        params: { id: 1 }, // params
        query: { ver: new Date().getTime() } // query params
      })
}
```

the final url will look something like: `http://localhost:5173/order/1?ts=1699792710908`

by using the `router.replace` instead of `router.push` - you are basically replacing the current path on the browser's history stack. So when the user clicks back - he will instead be forwarded to some previous page of the past
instead of the same page but without the timestamp query parameter in the url. Hope it makes sense.

I am yet to find any shortcomings of this approach, so please let me know in the comments if it has any drawbacks.

p.s. is valid for `vuejs` version `3`

Answer (score 1):

With RouterLink

```js
//With RouterLink
<router-link 
  :to="{name:"router-name", prams:{paramName: paramValue}}"
>
Route Text
</router-link>

//With Methods

methods(){
  this.$router.push({name:'route-name', params:{paramName: paramValue}})
}
```

With Methods

```
methods(){
  this.$router.push({name:'route-name', params:{paramName, paramValue}})
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).