# How can I change only specific query params in current route vue-router?

Tags: vue-router

I try to make pagination in Nuxt Js project, 
so how can I change only page query params in my current route, and keep other query params with there values 
I have 3 query params :

```
      this.count = this.$route.query.count ?? 8
      this.page = this.$route.query.page ?? 1
      this.sort_by = this.$route.query.sort_by ?? 'latest'
```

```
  <li class="pagination-link" v-for="(page, key) in computed.lastPage" :key="key"
        :class="{ 'active': page === computed.currentPage }">
      <nuxt-link :to="'?page='+page" append
                 :class="{'current-link' : computed.currentPage === page}">
        {{ page }}
      </nuxt-link>
    </li>
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382388/how-to-set-url-query-params-in-vue-with-vue-router

Comment: Thanks, Yes I do this solution and It's working, but I'm looking for a solution using `<nuxt-link>` or `<router-link>`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your best friend - `destructuring assignment`. [JavaScript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Here is an example of how to use it in your case:

```
let query = this.$route.query;
let newPage = 100;
this.$route.query = {...query, page: newPage};
```

Without any additional variables it will look much cleaner:

```
this.$route.query = {...this.$route.query, page: 100};
```

After code execution you will have `query` with overwritten `page` parameter to 100 and the remaining untouched parameters.

**PS. Updated on 19.11.2019**

As mentioned in comments, `$route` object is read-only. 
Change to `$router.replace` or `$router.push`:

```
this.$router.replace({name: path_name, query: {...this.$route.query, page: 100}})
```

Comment: The route object is read-only according to the docs, so how does this not throw a type error?

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'params' of object '#<Object>'` It is definitely throwing a type error.

Comment: `$router.replace` worked for me. I was was able to remove all query params with `$router.replace({ query: {} })`

Comment: for me, using Nuxt, ```this.$router.replace``` results in ```NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location``` error. But ```this.$router.push({ query: { ...this.$route.query, foo: 'bar' } })``` works without errors.

Comment: there is any other option without error in console por navigaton duplicated?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
this.$router.push({path: this.$route.path, query: { ...this.$route.query, foo: 'bar' }})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, this is a tricky situation w the Vue router. I've posted the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68822330/8904981
for a similar question

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt.js (will be similar in vue) :

```
this.$router.replace(`${this.$route.path}?page=${this.page}`)
```

`this.$router.replace` will replace the current path with the given string without pushing the change to the history [link](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

`this.route.path` will query the current path without any queryString (use `this.$route.fullPath` for the route with query strings)