# Dynamic query in Vue Router gives an error

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to use a dynamic query in vue router but I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
let selected = this.currentPage;
this.$router.replace({name: '', query: {...this.$route.query, page: selected }});
```

Error in console:

> Navigating to current location ("/?page=5") is not allowed

I have tried the solution here [How can I change only specific query params in current route vue-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347192/how-can-i-change-only-specific-query-params-in-current-route-vue-router) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you try to redirect to the same page. To prevent this try something like this

```
let selected = this.currentPage;
if (selected !== this.$route.query.page)
  this.$router.replace({name: '', query: {...this.$route.query, page: selected }});
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: It's this.$route.query.page instead of this.$router.query.page