# use form model in vue router push

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am writing a component to filter data in a grid.
The component has multiple fields in which I store their data in the model. when a user fills in some input and submits the form I am doing this on submit.

```
methods: {
    async submit() {
      await this.$router.push(
        {
          name: this.$route.name,
          query: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model))
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

I expect this to push the form data in the URL query but it won't do anything and I get this error.

```
Avoided redundant navigation to current location
```

It looks like I can't pass a dynamic value to the query. If I log the model in the console and paste the exact data in the code for the query it works without any problem!!
Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to switch to the same route you already are on?

Comment: I am trying to push query to the route

Comment: Well I see but how is this useful?  What do you use that query for? You should really expand your question with more info about what are you trying to achieve....

Comment: @MichalLevý there is a component responsible to generate filtering forms for different grids so it has dynamic fields. I have the data of that form in the model. I must push the data in the query so the grid refreshes and show the filtered data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using catch block..

```
this.$router.push(
        {
          name: this.$route.name,
          query: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model))
        }).catch(()=>{});
```

In this way, it allows you to only avoid the error displaying, because browser thinks the exception was handled.

Comment: But it won't fix the problem. I need to actually push the query to the route.

Comment: Yes you cant passed the object in that way I guess

Comment: Check these links https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382388/how-to-set-url-query-params-in-vue-with-vue-router

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I don't know how but I used to sync the form to the `this.$route.query`. So, when I was filling the form the query was getting updated. Obviously, when I was trying to push the query, the Vue router thought the query is redundant and raised that error.

Comment: @AdamOrlov I don't actually know how I did it but I passed `this.$route.query` as a param to the component with the name `resourceParams`. In the data of my component I had a line like this `model: this.resourceParams` I just changed it to `model: { ...this.resourceParams }` and this fixed the issue.