# Vuejs go to anchor after redirection

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

in my `<div id="app">.....</div>` i have something like the following

```
        <div class="fp-row4-content">
            ... ROW 1 ...
        </div>
            <div class="partition-line"></div>
        <div class="fp-row4-content">
            ... ROW 2 ...
        </div>
            <div class="partition-line"></div>
        <div class="fp-row4-content">
            ... ROW 3...
        </div>
            <div class="partition-line"></div>
        <div class="fp-row4-content">
            ... ROW 4 ...
        </div>
            <div class="partition-line"></div>
        <div class="fp-row4-content">
            ... ROW 5 ...
        </div>
```

If I click on each of these row, they will bring me to the same page. But after the page load, I want them to jump to 5 different specific anchor.

Is it possible to do it with Vuejs (I am using Laravel) ? Will vue-router do the job?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to jump to a specific location in the same page, you can use Vue Router and create a method to scroll to it like:

```
new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    scrollBehavior: function(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.hash) {
            return {selector: to.hash}
        } else {
            return { x: 0, y: 0 }
        }
    },
    routes: [
        {path: '/', component: abcView},
        // your routes
    ]
});
```

Extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341939/how-to-create-anchor-tags-with-vue-router).

Or create a method in the same page:

```
//Your view:
<a class="link-button" @click="scrollMeTo('section')">Jump</a>
...
<div ref="section" class="section1">

//JS
methods: {
  scrollMeTo(refName) {
    var element = this.$refs[refName];
    var top = element.offsetTop;

    window.scrollTo(0, top);
  }
}
```

You can take a look to the official documentation of [Scroll Behaviour](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) and here a jsfiddle with an example: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/gucLhzaL/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: i want to jump to a specific location in a different page. So it jumps to the anchor after redirecting to the page