# Vue.js: Scroll down using an anchor and a query

Tags: javascript, scroll, vue.js, anchor, query-string

I receive a notification from API with these parameters:

```
{
  "id": 12345,
  "created_at": "2018-01-15 11:40:30 +0000",
  "message": "Hi!",
  "object_id": 12,
  "anchor": "1543",
  "notification_type": "comment_created",
  "viewed": true
}
```

When a user clicks on the notification, he/she must be addressed to the post page, then this page must be scrolled down to the new added comment. I need to use an anchor from API and a query parameter to do this but I don't quite understand how.

Here is the component:

```
<template>
<div>
<span>
  <i class="g-font-size-18 g-color-gray-light-v1"></i>
</span>
<router-link :to="linkFromNotification(item)
             @click.native="linkFromNotification(item.notification_type)">
  <p>
    <span v-html="item.message"></span>
  </p>
</router-link>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex'


export default {
props: ['item'],
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    'getNotifications'
  ])
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions([
    'readNotification'
  ]),
  linkFromNotification (item) {
        if (item.notification_type === 'user_subscribed') {
          return {name: 'person', params: {id: item.object_id}}
        } else if (['comment_created', 'answer_selected', 'answer_created'].includes(item.notification_type)) {
          return {name: 'show_post', params: {id: item.object_id}}
        } else if (item.notification_type === 'user_coauthored') {
          return {name: 'show_post', params: {id: item.object_id}}
        }
      }
    }
   }
   </script>
```

I assume that I can add query parameter inside `linkFromNotification` where I return a post, and pass a `comment.id` or an `anchor`. Then I can add a watcher to see if comments are rendered to the page. Please help me to develop this thought and add query to the function `linkFromNotification` which construct the URL.

Comment: I have given an answer below based on the limited info above.  I can revise my answer to be more specific if needed as you reveal more details about how you render your notification, posts, or comment components.

Comment: I see your problem is quite different and more complex than I originally assumed so I removed my answer which really did not apply.

Comment: Yes you do have the problem using vue-router where the browser wont scroll to the anchor because the DOM is not ready until each of the comment components are render.    But  vue-router has built in support for this behavior.   https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

Comment: Okay, I see. I still hope to solve this. :)

Comment: But then I need to use coordinates. Is there any other way?

Comment: look further down in the documentation you can scroll `to.hash`   This answer here may help you too.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341939/how-to-create-anchor-tags-with-vue-router

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will try to apply this.